# Что такое "защита от подделки"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, defender

Защитник Windows хочет чтобы ему включили "защиту от подделки". Что это вообще такое и что оно делает?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Это что-ли?Tamper Protection: [Защита параметров безопасности](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/prevent-changes-to-security-settings-with-tamper-protection), [предотвращение изменений](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/4490103/windows-10-prevent-changes-to-security-settings-with-tamper-protection)

Comment: @Assur, знакомо, но какое оно имеет отношение к моему вопросу?

Comment: @Daemon-5, вроде оно. Ответ напишешь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В предварительных версиях обновления 19H1 разработчик Microsoft усовершенствовал приложение «Безопасность Windows», добавив возможность устанавливать настройку **Tamper Protection** (**Защита от подделки**). При активации данной функции будет задействована дополнительная защита от модификации ключевых настроек безопасности. Функционал официально [запущен](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-atp/tamper-protection-now-generally-available-for-microsoft-defender/ba-p/911482) в октябре 2019 г.

Описание [есть](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/prevent-changes-to-security-settings-with-tamper-protection) на сайте производителя.